# Reference two cells to determine value in invoice

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 sheets within the same workbook. One is a template for an invoice and the other is the list of items in one column A and a list of prices in column B. Utilizing data validation, B20:B30 auto-populates a dropdown list from the inventory sheet from items in column A. What I would like to do is have the unit price on the invoice auto-populate based on the inventory sheet depending on what item you choose from the dropdown in column B.

Any advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use `vlookup()`, like this:

```
=vlookup(B20, Prices!A$2:B, columns(Prices!A$2:B), false)
```

See [vlookup() help page](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093318).